# Unable to install mysqlclient using pycharm

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

unable to find the fix for it. Here is the output from the console. I have tried using different python interpreters and also downloaded mysql

```
pip
        The following command was executed:
        pip install mysqlclient==2.1.0
        The exit code: 1
        The error output of the command:
        Collecting mysqlclient==2.1.0
        Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
        Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
        Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
        Failed to build mysqlclient
        Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
        Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: started
        Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: finished with status 'error'
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: 'D:\Nutrition\Source Code\context\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gunot\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4xfatye_\\mysqlclient_5cf00f5723004ef1a4f6fe1a1f9673d1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gunot\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4xfa... (show balloon)
```